# How does one use Tim Pope's cucumber.vim plugin for vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, cucumber

I've loaded the cucumber.vim files into ftplugin and the other directories per instructions, but I don't understand the ftplugin syntax enough to figure out how to get the full benefits.

From what I can tell, the plugin is supposed to be able to jump between step definitions and feature files, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my mapping. It looks as if the mapping is supposed to be the usual ctag map Ctrl+], but that's not working.

Any ideas how to make those mappings work?

Here's a link to the plugin:

http://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber/tree/master

Cheerio!

Comment: Heh...usually people are so eager to answer...any particular reason why noone's popped in?

Comment: Where did you find this cucumber ftplugin ?

Comment: Tim Pope, creator of the Rails vim plugin created this one:

http://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber/tree/master

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have filetype plugin and filetype indent features turned on.

Just add the following to your .vimrc file:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: On Ubuntu you need to add a line before that one that says "filetype off" to force everything to be reloaded.

Comment: Also, for using any Vim plugin in general, Vundle (https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/) is awesome.